# Working with Forms in Shopware

Tags: shopware

I am unable to understand how forms work in shopware. I need to update the contact page with my own style but when I add content into the contact page cannot see that content on page when I browse it.

Could you please let me know how to create a page and what need to be done to add a form to that page?

Answer (score 7):

You are aware that the contact form is handled via configuration that can be done in the shopware backend's content > form section? there you will find a list of existing forms that can be modified by clicking the pen icon. A window will open where you can configure the forms name, the recipient email address, subject, email template as well as the form html content that will be shown in the frontend and the message that appears after submitting the form.

If you intend to change the layout (html and/or css) of the forms you need to override the forms template files:

- frontend/forms/elements.tpl
- frontend/forms/header.tpl
- frontend/forms/index.tpl

Kind regards!